# Ruby: Sort array by a foat field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

i have this code:

```
response = Place.all

    nearPlaces = []
    for el in response
      distance = el.distance_to([41.9097306,12.2558141])
      if distance < 20
        el.distance = distance
        nearPlaces.push(el)
      end
    end

    orderPlaces = nearPlaces.sort_by{|e| e[:distance]}
```

But the array is not sort by distance filed...any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nearPlaces.sort_by(&:distance)
```

Comment: @SaroVin it is impossible :)

Comment: more details => `_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected & orderPlaces = nearPlaces.sort_by{&:distance} ^`

Comment: @SaroVin look at braces, it should be `()`, not `{}`

Comment: Sorry, the problem is {}